# Multiple forms in one controller in Symfony3

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to use two forms in one controller. Each of them uses diffrent entity. Everytime i try to use second form, the first one executes. How to make it right?

```
    $document = new Document();

    $form2 = $this->createFormBuilder($document)
        ->add('file', FileType::class, array('label' => 'Wgraj plik '))
        ->add('name', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Nazwa dodawanego pliku'))
        ->add('toFill', CheckboxType::class, array('label' => 'Do wypełnienia?', 'required' => false))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Dodaj plik'))
        ->getForm();


    if ($form2->handleRequest($request)->isValid() && $form2->isSubmitted()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $document->upload();
        $document->setFormId($id);

        $em->persist($document);
        $em->flush();


    }

    $raportFiles = new RaportFiles();

    $formRaportsInput = $this->createFormBuilder($raportFiles)
        ->add('file', FileType::class, array('label' => 'Wgraj plik '))
        ->add('name', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Nazwa dodawanego pliku'))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Dodaj plik'))
        ->getForm();


    if ($formRaportsInput->handleRequest($request)->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $raportFiles->upload();
        $raportFiles->setFormId($id);

            $em->persist($raportFiles);
            $em->flush();
    }
```

I tried using `$this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder()` instead, but i can't get it to work.

Comment: Back to basics.  Your browser is only going to submit one form at a time so trying to process two or more forms in one action can get messy.  Your best bet is probably to make individual POST actions for each form.

Comment: @Cerad, he doesn't want to submit both forms at once, but be able to submit only one of them. The issue is that his code thinks that always the first form is submitted.

Comment: @dragoste, Exactly.  There is nothing in his code to distinguish between the two forms. Setting the action method to two different methods will make the problem go away.

Comment: @Cerad, your comment suggested that you thought he's trying to submit both forms at once. ;-)

Comment: I have 2 forms in twig template, both on different tabs. I want to be able to submit both separetly, not together. @Cerad but how to do this in symfony?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @Cerad but how to do this in symfony?

Start by defining three routes, one uses GET to display both forms.  The other two uses POST to process an individual form.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/requirements.html#adding-http-method-requirements

```
forms_show:
    path:     /forms
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:FormsController:show }
    methods:  [GET]
form_document_post:
    path:     /form-document
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:FormsController:documentPost }
    methods:  [POST]
form_raport__files_post:
    path:     /form-raport-files
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:FormsController:raportFilesPost }
    methods:  [POST]
```

Your controller needs three action methods.  Lets assume you have made form types just to save some typing.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes

```
class FormsController {
    public function showAction() {
        $document = new Document();
        $documentForm = $this->createForm(DocumentType::class,$document,array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('form_document_post')));

        $raportFiles = new RaportFiles();
        $raportFilesForm = $this->createForm(RaportFilesType::class,$raportFiles,array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('form_raport_files_post')));

        // Return the processed template
    }
    // Only gets called when the document form is posted
    public function documentPostAction(Request $request)
    {
        $document = new Document();
        $documentForm = $this>createForm(DocumentType::class,$document);
        $documentForm->handleRequest($document);
        if ($documentForm->isValid()) {
            // Persist
            return $this->redirectToRoute('forms_show');
        }
        // You will have to decide how you want to handle form errors
    }
    // Repeat for second form
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank You very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a specific form is submitted by doing this :

```
$form2->handleRequest($request);    
if ( $form2->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid() ){
    ...
}

$formRaportsInput->handleRequest($request);     
if ( $formRaportsInput->isSubmitted() && $formRaportsInput->isValid() ){
    ... 
}
```

This will make the job ;)

EDIT : And this is on the same controller action of course !

Comment: Great idea but it won't work.  Try it.  You could make it work by doing some checks directly in the request object but it would get messy and be a bit of a hack.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately that was first step in my fight with forms. It's not working.

Comment: That might be because you create your forms in two different action, regroup its and try again, it works for me.